# Limitations Of Ohms Law

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, bjt, ohms-law

Sometimes i think why the heck this ohms law created to make troubles for us, as nowadays i am deeply working on Basic Electronics so there Ohms law actually sucks... I was studying transistor configurations, where in (CB) amplifier where he have no current gain but there voltage gain is whooping ?? How is that possible inverse relation between current and voltage, similarly in (CC) Amplifier where the current gain is touching the skies while voltage gets attenuates.. I mean where does this Ohms Law fall there again now i am studying DC bias of BJT where in Emitter bias a emitter current increases then voltage across base decreases i am confused...

Comment: Every tool has its applicability domain, and one needs to know it before using blindly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this because it does not appear to be a question.

Comment: Ohm lived long before transistors were a thing.  Cut him some slack!   Seriously though, Ohms law only works with linear components  i.e. resistors or impedances.   It doesn't work with active components like transistors.  You need other techniques to analyze those things.

Comment: Your "question" has been closed because you didn't ask a question. If you have a specific question then please [edit], remove the rant and ask a specific question about some one point where you are stuck or confused. The question may then be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Ohm's Law only applies to ideal resistors. It doesn't apply at all to non-linear elements like transistors and diodes, and can have significant errors when applied to real-world resistors.

Ohm's Law is an approximation...a **model**... of real behavior. And George Box said it best: "All models are wrong, some are useful."

Comment: It applies pretty well to non-ideal resistors too. It looks like the OP is trying to apply it to ..that is.. non-ohmic elements.